# securing communication between 2 MVC apps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, identityserver4

I have 2 MVC apps. [mvcApp1 & mvcApp2].
Both apps have individual logins using aspNet Identity. Using C# dotnetcore 3.1
So the structure looks like this MVC1[aspNet Id1] & MVC2[aspNet Id2]

I want to send data from MVC1[aspNet Id1] => MVC2[aspNet Id2]

How would i go about only allowing communication between the 2 apps?

Would I perhaps use a token service like identity server 4? [though i'm under the impression that this requires users to login to identity server]

Would an API key system perhaps be appropriate?

Comment: There are way to many approaches to that... Starting from just hardcoded random value known to both services, client side certificates for HTTPS, Azure AD or any other authentication the shared between servers, using just user auth (requires somehow syncing users).... You may want to figure out what your options are and try to implement first..

Comment: You can use the client credentials grant type for [machine to machine communication](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#machine-to-machine-communication). This flow does not require users, so you don't have to configure users. It's not a user that logs in but the client (using a secret as password). With [extension grants](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html) you can create custom credentials.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, yes, I see that in identity server 4. Briefly, what would be the disadvantage of just an APIkey system between the two MVC clients?

Comment: @Shane.A can you explain a bit more about communication between the 2 apps? are you sending data between apps from client side or server side? is this communication just for logged-in users?

Comment: @nahidf Thanks for the question. Both MVC apps are in dotnet core 3 and exist on a server. There are not any client side components yet. The communication is for usurers logged in.

Comment: Just for API communication the IdentityServer4 would be an overkill but it is the right way if you are going to introduce clients in near future. So if you go with the IdentityServer4 then you would have to create a new MVC app which would provide access tokens. And the MVC1 and MVC2 would be clients and API resources.